# How can I make my iPad apps retina in Xcode 5 iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, storyboard, xcode5

Not long ago I started learning Objective-C with an interest of developing apps. I have just started my first app and I have no clue how to make my app retina. I made the design in photoshop and exported it as a png @ 2,048 x 1,536 but however the size of my storyboard is only 1,024 x 768. I have read somewhere on the internet that you need two story boards but I am not sure how to link everything together. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No we don't need two storyboards for this. In storyboard, the view size will be 1024 x 768. You have to design the views for same sizes and keep images for these sizes only. Example, if you are making an UIImageView of size 100 x 100, then you will need to set its image of size 100 x 100 only. Now the extra effort required is:
If you named that image as test.png of size 100 x 100, then you have to add same image with name test@2x.png and size 200 x 200 to your project folder.

Now when the application will run on non retina divice, then it will by default take test.png and when the app will run on retina device, then test@2x.png will be used. This is default property you don't need to set this any where in code.

So make your views as usual and just keep images with @2x.png in project folder. Rest things will be managed automatically.

Comment: Thankyou Ashu, this should help a lot.

Comment: Always welcome, and if it helps, then please dont forget to tick the answear as this may help others too using this forum.:)

Comment: Just as an addition: if you only have one of the two versions (either only `test.png` or only `test@2x.png`), on devices that don't match that mode, the image will be scaled up/down to fit *at run time*. So when you're merely prototyping using dummy graphics, you don't need both versions (scaling at runtime will result in a small performance hit, and possibly increased memory usage).

Answer (score 0):

What is Retina Display

@1X is a resolution (or rather, a process) in which many designers still design apps. Why? Because (and as many would have to agree) designing at such is much more tangible. I find it hard to explain why it’s so, but all I can say is that the content feels much more 1 on 1, it feels right so to speak, and the design is much more flexible to deal with, because of our “low” resolution computer displays that we’re designing them on.
Though that doesn’t mean we all like designing @1X. I’ve seen many others who build wonderful, beautiful apps designing at both processes (the other would have to be @2X — resolution of that of the Retina Display) and some say it feels much more comfortable for them having to have their content match perfectly without having to scale things up and tweak things around on the display.

More Dtails [2x-the-retina-dilemma](http://theindustry.cc/2012/03/30/2x-the-retina-dilemma/)

How identify the retina display

```
#define IS_RETINA_DISPLAY ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] && ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0))

if(IS_RETINA_DISPLAY)
{
   // RETINA_DISPLAY 
}else{
  // NON_RETINA_DISPLAY 
}
```

Now, that the iPad has been released, I’m sure you are all scrambling for ideas on how to snag a piece of the market in the imminent gold rush. some of below links is going to help you on your journey with a series of iPad tutorials to come.

[ipad-programming-tutorial-hello-world](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/04/05/ipad-programming-tutorial-hello-world/)

[How-To-Develop-iPad-Apps](http://ipad.about.com/od/iPad-App-Dev/a/How-To-Develop-iPad-Apps.htm)

Comment: The `@2x` naming scheme should really be your first approach, and in most cases it'll be all you need. You shouldn't be checking manually in code unless you *really* need to (and if you're not sure when you'd need to, you probably don't need to).

Answer (score 0):

please follow bellow tutorial for iOS.It's a first step towards the iOS.
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/
http://www.raywenderlich.com

Answer (score 0):

I am new to iOS development too. This link has been a huge help on questions related to this. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html

You can pull up the same thing in the Xcode documentation by searching "app-related".